# unable to send ajax request on php

Tags: javascript

I am using sending an ajax request on php. In form method i m using the following code.

rohit1.php

```
<form action="index1.php" onsubmit="callfunc()">
<span id="raj"></span>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></div>

</FORM>
```

in javascript i m using:
callfun.js

```
function callfunc()
{

var http =new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var name=prompt('enter name of the form');
    var name="rohit";
    var url = "index1.php";
    var s = document.getElementById('raj').innerHTML;
    alert(http);
    http.open("POST", "index1.php?name="+name, true);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
        {


        }




    }

    http.send();
}
```

when i am using this function. then on submit this is redirecting on index.php?label=  instead of index.php?name=  what should I do for this???

Comment: Are just trying to redirect to new page. OR you want to do some else

Comment: window.location.href="index1.php?name="+name; will work for you then

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add `return false` at the end of `callfunc()` function. It will prevent the form's default event and will not act as a standard form.

Comment: yes, visually nothing should happen, if you want to send an ajax request to the server you have to handle the response in the `if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)` statement that you've wrote.

Comment: and I don't see any code that contains word "label", I guess that the problem could be a little typo somewhere in your code?

Comment: @rab nawaz  I want to redirect on index1.php from rohit1.php

Comment: Try an alert. if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) 
        {

              alert("I am back");
        }

Comment: @hayner I dont want any response. but i want to send the value of var name to my php file i.e index1.php.

Comment: do you want just to redirect or pass some parameters? and why you use ajax if you just want to redirect?

Comment: @kiranvj I am not getting any response

Comment: then you don't need this ajax code (by the way this code will NOT work on IE), just use `window.location.href="index1.php?name="+name;` and that will redirect you to the desired page with the desired parameter

Comment: @haynar actually the label is the name of label in my form. but in form i am posting only on index1.php with post method. then why i am getting this problem

Comment: when you use "name" attribute inside html FORM element, the browser tries to send the value of each element that have attribute "name", so in this case (I guess you use IE, that's why you don't get response) it tries to send the value of label as it has "name" attribute

Comment: no i dont have any error on the page but in address bar i m getting redirected

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="index1.php" onsubmit="callfunc()">
    <span id="raj"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>
```

and the appropriate javascript will look like this:

```
function callfunc() {
    var name = "some name here"; // get this name from whereever you want
    window.location.href = "index1.php?name="+name;
    return false;
}
```

this should work for you

Comment: I have also tried this one but it is getting the same response